# Why doesn't my Union of interfaces work?

Tags: typescript

I have an interface called `IContact` which will be included within a response object, either as a single object or as an array. I've tried to code that in an interface

```
export interface ResponseObject {
    data:IContact|Array<IContact>;

}
```

But I'm getting

> error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'IContact | IContact[]'.

Put another way

my app compiles with `data:IContact` simply by adding "|string" to make `data:IContact|string` it fails with the above error.

How should I correctly define my interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works fine as shown below:

```
interface IContact {
    name: string;
}
interface ResponseObject {
    data: IContact|Array<IContact>;
}

var response: ResponseObject = {
    data: {
        name: '123'
    }
};
```

[Try it online](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=interface%20IContact%20%7B%0D%0A%09name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20ResponseObject%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20data%3A%20IContact%7CArray%3CIContact%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20response%3A%20ResponseObject%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09data%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09name%3A%20'123'%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A)

Notes:

a.) make sure you have TS 1.4 installed for visual studio.

b.) Webstorm doesn't support TS 1.4 unless you use the beta channel.

Comment: it's weird. if I paste my code online (merging a referenced .d.ts for the interface definition) it works. In my code, if I replace the union with a simple object (ie. erase from the pipe character), it works. As soon as I add even '|string' I get the above error.

Comment: Make sure you have TypeScript 1.4 for visual studio installed. Alternatively give https://atom.io/packages/atom-typescript a go ;)

Comment: Originally I found I was still using 1.3, so upgraded to 1.4.1.0. What's odd is that in WebStorm, it still shows an error at the pipe character "expecting newline or semicolon" as if it's still running 1.3. I'll have a look at atom.

Comment: Upvote for the atom suggestion. Very nice indeed. I've updated my question just in case you have any other suggestions on my error.

Comment: Webstorm hasn't update to TypeScript 1.4. You can use their beta channel to get that support now or wait a bit more.

Comment: k, well for now I'm quite liking Atom. Having said that, the error I'm getting is from tsc 1.4.1 and also Atom, so the problem goes on.

Comment: I've figured it out. It was a problem in the code where I was doing the data.name. I'm still not quite sure why it was only triggered with a union type, but I re-factored that code and the problem went away. I've accepted your answer as it correctly confirms that what I was doing should have worked, and the additional help with atom and WS10.